# collection_select giving ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, collections

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question right or am just too tired for it to be obvious.

My code is:

_form.html.haml

```
 = f.collection_select :category, Category.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name
```

What I get is

```
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in LinksController#create
 Category(#70203963939880) expected, got String(#70203929255820)
```

Log is

```
 Started POST "/links" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-12 22:14:05 -0800
 Processing by LinksController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z4RYcUW3hGLfKBAwQLMZbye2I1mn16fg6BSBGe7GILU=", "link"=>{"name"=>"SFGate", "url"=>"http://www.sfgate.com/", "category"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms
```

It appears as though its passing :id as a string instead of an integer.  Any clues?

Update:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :links

  attr_accessible :name, :color, :position

  COLOR_CODES = ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange", "Red", "Purple", "Pink"]
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :category, :name, :position, :url, :user_id
end
```

Fixed:  I had

```
 t.integer :category
```

instead of

```
 t.integer :category_id
```

switched everything over and its working perfect - I guess I was too tired :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
f.collection_select :category, Category.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name
```

to:

```
f.collection_select :category_id, Category.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name
```

Comment: I get the error: NoMethodError in Links#new  undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol

Comment: do you have a foreign key `category_id` in your model? What are you doing with form?

Comment: I made that change and it still gave me the merge error - I updated to include my models

Comment: you don't have a column `category_id` in table Links? if you have, you should define in your model: `attr_accessible :category_id`, not `attr_accessible :category`

Comment: haha - that was it exactly - I switched my DB to t.integer :category_id and it works.