# How to correctly use collection_select along with custom associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a patient profile mode like this:-

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eyes, class_name: "EyeColor", foreign_key: "eyes"
end
```

the database table has an integer called eyes

I have an EyeColor model which simply has an ID and Description (text for the colour)

and I've made a form which has a collection_select on it like this:-

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eyes %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :eyes, EyeColor.all, :id, :description  %>
</div>
```

now when I attempt to update the record via the form, I get the following:-

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (EyeColor(#45428760) expected, got String(#19387428))
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the form structure will look for an `:eyes` attribute and assign it the string value the select will send for it. But the Rails engine is expecting an `EyeColor`object for this attribute, not a `String`.
You should change the name of your foreign key:

```
belongs_to :eye, class_name: "EyeColor", :foreign_key: "eye_id"
```

or better:

```
belongs_to :eyecolor
```

With this, you need a table named eye_colors, a class named `EyeColor`, and a foreign key `eye_color_id`.

Question already asked by the way:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356481/2943357

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw that other question but didn't understand how to apply it to my situation, I see what I've done now, thanks!

Comment: Also, change the select line:
`<%= f.collection_select :eye_color_id, EyeColor.all, :id, :description  %>`

Comment: should that be belongs_to :eyecolor (no "s")?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I haven't mentioned that mistake.