# Cannot figure out how to make a form for my has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three tables:
**Sales**, **Types**, **SaleTypes**.

```
class Sales < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_types
  has_many :types, through: :sale_types
end


class Types < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_types
  has_many :sales, through: :sale_types
end


class SaleType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :sale
  belong_to :type
end
```

I have a form on the Sales edit page that is a multi-select for Types:

```
<%= f.collection_select :type_ids, Spree::Taxonomy.all, :id, :name, {selected: @sale.types}, {multiple: true} %>
```

However, when it submits, I get: uninitialized constant `SaleTypes::Types` -- which makes no sense. I have set the `class_names` for everything set. Additionally, when I set the `collecition_select` to just :types, it gets this error:
`Type(#1234) expected, got String(#4567)`

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: have you tried maybe using 'Type' as singular instead, maybe?

Comment: Because you probably have a Type class instead of a Types class

Comment: Duplicated question. You'll find the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127405/how-to-correctly-use-collection-select-along-with-custom-associations/20127855#20127855

Comment: @YannGuillemot that does not answer my question -- I already have the pass-through table.

Comment: Singular table name isn't the issue. I think I am assuming rails can handle this in a simple update_attributes call, but I will try to set the Types before updating and see if that works.

Comment: So I set the Sale.types to Types.find(params[:type_ids], and the update worked. Weird because the update_attributes call is exactly the same, alas.